# How to optimize memory for very long navigation stack of UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, memory, uinavigationcontroller

I have some scenarios in my app in which the navigation stack becomes very long because of the number of `UIViewControllers` I push. I am building something similar to a file explorer UI in my app and there is a chance lots of `UIViewControllers` will be pushed in the navigation stack. For very deep navigation stack I run into memory warnings.

In the app, we need to only show the current `UIViewController` all previous `UIViewConrollers` are in memory. Can we optimize this and add some sort of virtualization to improve memory footprint ?

Comment: you have a lot of options to do, but everything depends on your code. First, you can initialize elements in viewWillAppear and free them on viewWillDisapaer. Also, you can play with the navigation controller to have last 3 view controllers and when you open the second one to use navigationController.viewControllers = list_of_last_3

Comment: @m1sh0 You should write that as an answer. There's really very little else to say about it! I wouldn't want to give an answer that copies what you've already said in your comment.

Comment: I just add the answer maybe there should be some modifications in the code, but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you have `UIViewController` for each folder.

I think there is no problem if you keep just the last 3 controllers. And on `viewWillApear` of each `UIViewController` you have a check for older view controllers and to remove some view controllers

Maybe something like this in `viewWillAppear`

```
if (navigationController?.viewControllers.count)! > 3 {
    navigationController?.viewControllers.removeFirst()
} else if (navigationController?.viewControllers.count)! < 2 {
     if true {
          let olderPage = UIViewController()
          navigationController?.viewControllers.insert(olderPage, at: 0)
     }
}
```

For sure you can play more with the stuff that you have in the View Controller and initialize as much as you can in `viewWillApear` and free as much as you can in `viewWillDisapear`. Have in mind that if you load images with `UIImage(named:)` image will be cached and they will not dealoc the memory.